# \title is listed as section in table of contents (apa6 documentclass)

Tags: table-of-contents, apa6

This is the code for the probem I've got with my Latex-Project. I'm using sharelatex.

```
\documentclass[man,floatsintext,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Problem}
\author{Lisa Lustig}
\date{\today}
\shorttitle{Problem}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\section{Methods}
\end{document}
```

And my table of contents looks like this:
[image]

I don't get any errors but I still think the marked parts don't belong there ^^ It seems like the `\title` I defined earlier is regarded as some kind of section. Even if I leave `\title` undefined the space keeps being "reserved":
[image]

I spent quite some time developing an unorthodox workaround for this problem using white boxes that are placed at the exact coordinates of the unwanted text but it still bothers me beause I just can't understand why this happens and even if you can't see the text there is still the unwanted space.

The whole document has to be formatted according to the apa6 guidelines for manuscripts and citations have to be apa6 style as well. Is there another way to get this working *including* a properly working table of contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `apa6` repeats the title as section. You can avoid this using option `donotrepeattitle`:

```
\documentclass[man,floatsintext,apacite,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Problem}
\author{Lisa Lustig}
\date{\today}
\shorttitle{Problem}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\section{Methods}
\end{document}
```

[image]